# regular expression to match two words with a space

Tags: regex

I am looking for the regular expression needed to match the follow pattern

*hello, **hello world**, helloworld*

I would only want the bold set to be picked up (the space included.)

Comment: Is this the specific words, or any words? Because right now I'd say use "hello world" as your regex ;)

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? something like `/hello, (hello world), helloworld/` would work, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: They aren't the specific words :P

Comment: What if the string is `hello, hello world, hello world`, what do you want matching?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\w+\s\w+`

At least one word character, then a space (or tab, or what have you), then at least another word character.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: `\w` matches alphanumeric characters so it could also match "**hello 1**" for example

Comment: True. If OP wants to restrict it to just letters and i18n isn't an issue, `[a-zA-z]` could be used.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` is problematic for UTF-8 input

Answer (score 2):

```
^hello\sworld$
```

- ^ will anchor the beginning of the string, the $ will anchor the end of the string
- hello: matches the first word 'hello'
- \s: matches the space
- world: matches the second word 'world'

Answer (score 0):

`\b[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\b`

as `\w` could match numbers also.

`\b` is a *word boundary*