# How to use Angular Validators.pattern to validate an input with two words and a space in between?

Tags: angular

I am trying to have input validation that allows a user to input their first and last name into a text box. Unfortunately, I can't get the validator pattern to validate if the input has a first and last name separated by a space.

The validators for phone are working fine.

This is the HTML code that displays an error message if the validator fails. Everything is working fine except the validator pattern for first and last name

```
<input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && registerForm.controls['name'].errors}" formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
<div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['name'].errors" class="text-danger">
  <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['name'].errors['required']">
    Full name is required
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['name'].errors['minlength']">
    Full name should be at least 4 characters
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls['name'].errors['pattern']">
    Full name should include first and last name
  </div>   
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAxEN.png)

Answer (score 2):

For next time please don't upload a screenshot of your code but just add the code in the correct code tags. URL's to images might disappear and people in the future will not know what this question was about.

I was looking for some regex, maybe this one: `\w+\s\w+`
[regular expression to match two words with a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815197/regular-expression-to-match-two-words-with-a-space)

Also have a look at this: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example#FormBuilder

Comment: you would probably want to add anchors: ^ and $